# How do you position a custom UIPicker?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uipickerview

So I'm trying to position a custom UIPicker in my view. I am following the UICatalog code and applying the same principles in my code.

The way they seem to position it is:

```
CGSize pickerSize = [myPickerView sizeThatFits:CGSizeZero];
customPickerView.frame = [self pickerFrameWithSize:pickerSize];
```

How does that work? They seem to be calling "sizeThatFits" on a regular picker they have created elsewhere in the code (and which I don't need), and then use that to set up the frame.

How do I implement something like this without needing two pickers? I want my custom picker to be on the bottom of the view.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
myPickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 244, 320, 216)];
```

I found out the correct size and position by dragging  a regular view in a nib file and using the same coordinates.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in the [`documentation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW16), certain types of class of objects return fixed sizes. `UIPickerView` is one of them and is better left unchanged. So we get the appropriate size using that method on a `UIPickerView` object. You don't need a second instance for this. You can initialize a picker object without a frame and call this on it to get the appropriate size.

Comment: Ok I just don't understand is why it isn't some sort of static class constant in the UIPickerView class. It seems more logical to me to be able to get a constant from the class. Something like UIPickerView.size instead of initializing a picker object for the sole purpose of getting a value.